# Caching/Storing the LTPA token generated in datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower, ltpa, aaa-security-protocol

I'm generating an LTPA token in datapower after the authentication.

I want to store this token for further processing.(to validate against another request)

How can I store/cache this token in datapower?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on firmware 7.2 or 7.5 you can write to file system using GatewayScript or you can store it in a system variable (set-system-var) but I would advice against that!

Another option might be if you are using IBM MQ to store it as a topic.